# Why does `l2_cache_accesses_from_dc_misses` not include `l2_request_g1.ls_rd_blk_c_s` in zen2?

Tags: caching, perf, cpu-cache, amd-processor

Recently, I used `perf` to improve the program performance. It has two events `l2_cache_req_stat.ls_rd_blk_cs` and `l2_cache_req_stat.ls_rd_blk_l_hit_s` on my zen2 r7 4800h cpu. They can be seen in the [source codes](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1c7873e3364570ec89343ff4877e0f27a7b21a61/tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86/amdzen2/cache.json#L136). But it may be better to view it in the [17h A0h PPR doc revision](https://www.amd.com/en/support/tech-docs/processor-programming-reference-ppr-for-amd-family-17h-models-a0h-afh-revision-a0) (This model may be very new and not included in [wikichip cpuid](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/cpuid#Family_23_.2817h.29) when I posted. Although I use 17h 60h cpu, they are both zen2 17h family and used *the same PMCx064*) where AMD may give one more clear description about their differences.

the "Non-Modifiable" corresponds to "Shared" in [MOESI which is used by AMD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32616718/21294350) (this is also said in AMD64 Architecture Programmer’s Manual) and "Shared Read" probably includes one more state ("Owned"):

> Bits Description
>
> 7 LsRdBlkCS: Data Cache Shared Read Hit in L2. Read-write. Reset: 0.
>
> 5 LsRdBlkLHitS: Data Cache Read Hit **Non-Modifiable** Line in L2. Read-write. Reset: 0.

---

If so, on the different PMCx060 from the above PMCx064, [`l2_cache_accesses_from_dc_misses`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a901a3568fd26ca9c4a82d8bc5ed5b3ed844d451/tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86/amdzen2/recommended.json#L31C3-L31C20) ("L2 Cache Accesses from L1 Data Cache Misses (including prefetch)") don't have [`l2_request_g1.ls_rd_blk_c_s`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1c7873e3364570ec89343ff4877e0f27a7b21a61/tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86/amdzen2/cache.json#L18C15-L18C19) (Data cache shared reads) unit mask set.

Why does `l2_cache_accesses_from_dc_misses` not take `l2_request_g1.ls_rd_blk_c_s` in account?